# Disabling specific test instance defined from a dataset

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

Let's say I have the following test code:

```cpp
struct MyData
{
    MyData( int in_, double out_ )
    : m_in{ in_ }
    , m_out{ out_ }
    {}

    int    m_in;
    double m_out;
};

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os_, MyData data_ )
{
    os_ << data_.m_in << " " << data_.m_out << std::endl;
    return os_;
}

std::vector< MyData > DataSetGet()
{
    return
        {
            { 1, 1.0 },
            { 2, 2.0 }, // I would like to disable this...
            { 3, 3.0 },
        };
}

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE( CastIntToDouble, DataSetGet() )
{
    BOOST_TEST( static_cast< double >( sample.m_in ) == sample.m_out );
}
```

I would like to disable the second test instance. I could just comment out the second case, like this:

```cpp
std::vector< MyData > DataSetGet()
{
    return
        {
            { 1, 1.0 },
            //{ 2, 2.0 }, // I would like to disable this...
            { 3, 3.0 },
        };
}
```

but then this case would no longer be compiled, which is not what I am looking for. In my real scenario, test cases are more complex and I would like them compiled, but not run.

I have searched the boost documentation on this topic and I came across the [disable decorator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html), which looks like what I need. However, I have found no way to use it in data test cases. Is this possible?

Comment: `auto DataSetGet2() { auto res = DataSetGet(); res.pop_back(); /*or other filter*/ return res;}`?

Comment: Good point, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [supply a command line argument](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html#boost_test.runtime_config.test_unit_filtering.command_line_control), like:

```
./sotest -l all -t "!*/*_1"
```

Which outputs:

[image]

### More Advanced/Dynamic

You could also supply your own decorator based on enable_if, which you could make to use your own custom command line options (you'll need to supply your own `test_main` to parse those).

For an example of such custom decorator: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/enabling.html#boost_test.tests_organization.enabling.runtime_run_status

### Live Demo

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07d0a24a4a3be633)

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE StackOverflow
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/dataset.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test_parameters.hpp>

namespace but = boost::unit_test;
namespace utf = boost::unit_test_framework;

struct MyData {
    MyData(int in_, double out_) : m_in{in_}, m_out{out_} {}

    int    m_in;
    double m_out;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os_, MyData data_) {
    return os_ << data_.m_in << " " << data_.m_out << std::endl;
}

std::vector<MyData> DataSetGet()
{
    return {
        {1, 1.0},
        {2, 2.0}, // I would like to disable this...
        {3, 3.0},
    };
}

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(CastIntToDouble, DataSetGet())
{
    BOOST_TEST( static_cast< double >( sample.m_in ) == sample.m_out );
}
```

Run with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework
./a.out -l all -t "!*/*_1" --no_color_output
```

Prints

```
Running 2 test cases...
Entering test module "StackOverflow"
main.cpp(30): Entering test suite "CastIntToDouble"
main.cpp(30): Entering test case "_0"
main.cpp(32): info: check static_cast< double >( sample.m_in ) == sample.m_out has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    sample = 1 1
; 
main.cpp(30): Leaving test case "_0"; testing time: 443us
main.cpp(30): Test case "CastIntToDouble/_1" is skipped because disabled
main.cpp(30): Entering test case "_2"
main.cpp(32): info: check static_cast< double >( sample.m_in ) == sample.m_out has passed
Assertion occurred in a following context:
    sample = 3 3
; 
main.cpp(30): Leaving test case "_2"; testing time: 404us
main.cpp(30): Leaving test suite "CastIntToDouble"; testing time: 967us
Leaving test module "StackOverflow"; testing time: 1016us

*** No errors detected
```

Comment: Added a [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07d0a24a4a3be633)

Comment: Late addition: documentation for the command line control https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html#boost_test.runtime_config.test_unit_filtering.command_line_control